# Does derivative approaching a constant imply that the primitive is approaching a line?

Tags: calculus

Are there any examples of functions $f'(x)$ where $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f'(x) =C$$
but
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)\neq Cx+D  \ ?$$

My motivation for this idea is that the fact that $f'(x) \rightarrow 0$ does not imply that $f'(x)\rightarrow C$. A simple counterexample of $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ is enough to see this.

I would like the counterexample to be strong enough to conclude that $f(x)$ can't be approaching a line or anything that behaves like a line. This would be used to conclude that $\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x)$ does not need to have a horizontal asymptote as $x\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=Cx+D$ doesn't make any sense. What do you really mean?

Comment: But maybe all you need to do is to think about $f'(x)=C+(1/x)$.

Comment: If $f'(x)=C+1/x$ then $f(x)$ would still approach a line since $ln(x)$ approaches $x$?

Comment: In what universe does $\log x$ approach $x$?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you mean by $\ln x$ approaches $x$. It is not the case that $\ln x \sim x$ since $\lim \ln x/x = 0$.

Comment: I see now that you're asking about $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f$. Why should a limit at minus infinity have any relation to a limit at infinity?

Comment: Meant to have $-\infty$ in both limits - corrected. When I talk about 'approaching' in this context, it is to reason that the graph of the derivative of the inverse of $f$ does not need to have a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Just to clarify: if $f(x)=e^x,$ is $f^{-1}(x)=\ln(x)$? That is, $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$? If so, examples are easy to come by, since the behavior of $f^{-1}(x)$ as $x\to-\infty$ does not have to have much of anything to do with the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\,\to\,\text{something}} \Big( \cdot\cdots \Big),$ when it exists, is NOT something that depends on $x.$ The variable $x$ in this context is bound, not free. $\qquad$

Comment: You should write $\lim_{x \to -\infty} (f(x)-Cx-D)=0$. As others have already pointed out, the limit can't depend on $x$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x)\, = Cx+D  \, or \, D$ means it approaches an asymptotic line.If RHS is $g(x)$ it is a curved asymptote

Answer (score 6):

Probably the most well known counterexample to this is $f(x) = \log_e x.$ You have $f'(x) \to0$ as $x\to+\infty,$ but there is no non-vertical line that is an asymptote to the graph of this function.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understood your question correctly.

By: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = Cx + D$$ (non-standard notation, $x$ should not appear on the RHS) I take it that you mean: $$f(x) \sim Cx + D$$ in which case, an easy example is $f(x) = e^x$.

We have:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$$

but:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(Cx + D\right)e^{-x} = 0$$

for all $C$, $D$ by say, L'Hopital's rule, so it is not the case that $e^x \sim Cx + D$ for any $C, D$.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Note that the question has been corrected; it was supposed to be $x \to -\infty$ in both limits.